# C++ OpenGL not rebuilding correctly

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have written a basic OpenGL program that I am trying to debug. I disovered that there is an issue with how the code is being built via the following diagnosis steps:

After a certain amount of time, I start reaching the error 'A copy of a.cpp was found in somepath, but the current source code is different from the version built into somepath' any time a breakpoint is set. I have ensured that I force a rebuild and don't modify the source after doing so, as to ensure that the source and the build are in sync.

I have tried this in VS 2019, and then in VS 2022, and I get the same error. I am using OpenGL 3.3 with GLAD. I have also tried disabling the setting 'Require source files to exactly match the original version', which then allows the breakpoint to be hit, but then I can tell that the breakpoint is not actually running the current version of the source, as if I create a new variable with a new name, and then rebuild and run the code, it does not show this variable in the explorer.

Now I have discovered that if I force 'Rebuild' instead of 'Build', it fixes this error and runs the most up to date version of the code. So, there must be some issue of VS not checking properly that the code needs to be rebuilt. How can I ensure the code is properly rebuilt before running each time (how do I make sure that the 'build' button actually builds, instead of having to force a 'rebuild' each time?)

Comment: You should enable Detailed build logging at VS Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run page. Inspecting build log will clarify what is exactly going on during build.

Comment: Here's the build output https://pastebin.com/2XfYRXjX. I think there must be some issue with the compiler not recognising the changes while attempting to do a differential build.